# mongoose db problem, findOne() doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I know you don't care, but it's my second time here ^^'

Ok, so my problem is i'm trying to do a findone() and it's just doesnt work.. Any error or anything, there is my code :

The first findOne() so Data.findOne() perfectly work but the tech.findOne() just don't work
Yeah it's a french bot ^^'

```
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'profil':
            let user2 = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
            Data.findOne({
                userID: user2.id
            }, (err, data) => {
                console.log(data)
                if (err) console.log(err);
                if (data.fdd) {
                    tech.findOne({  
                        fruits: data.fdd
                    }), (error, fru) => {
                        console.log(err, fru)
                        if (error) console.log(error)
                        message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('YELLOW').setFooter(config.footer).setTitle(`${data.fdd}`).addFields(
                            { name: fru.name1, value: `Descriptions de la technique : ${fru.technique1}` },
                            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                            { name: fru.name2, value: `Descriptions de la technique : ${fru.technique2}` },
                            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                            { name: fru.name3, value: `Descriptions de la technique : ${fru.technique3}` },
                            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                            { name: fru.name4, value: `Descriptions de la technique : ${fru.technique4}` }
                        ).setURL(fru.links))
                    }
                } else return message.channel.send(`${user2} possède aucun fruit.`);
            })
            break;

    }
}
```

```
// what Data.findOne({userID : user2.id}) return
{
  _id: 60550c475af5981418433038,
  name: 'myusername',
  userID: 'myuserid',
  train: 0,
  fdd: 'Tori Tori no Mi, Model: Phoenix',
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: Could you show the model file for `tech`?

Comment: i just did, thanks you for your answer

Comment: @user15447158 Can you share the `Data` object returned by `Data.findOne({ userID: user2.id })`?

Comment: I'm doing this right now

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I add it to the post ^^

Comment: @user15447158 Thanks. It does have the `fdd` property. Can you try `console.log(err, fru)` and share the output?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan It's returning nothing

Comment: @user15447158 What do you mean by "It's returning nothing"? It should log something.

Comment: There's nothing in the console when i execute the command @ArunKumarMohan

Comment: @user15447158 Looks like the `console.log` statement isn't executed at all which is super weird. Can you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I just did, thanks you very much for helping me

Comment: @user15447158 `console.log(data)` logs the data right? Can you replace `console.log(err, fru)` with `console.log('Inside tech.findOne callback', error, fru)` and share the output?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan with the code : ```console.log(tech.findOne({fruits: data.fdd}), (err, fru))```
I got a error : node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: fru is not defined

And yea console.log(data) log the data

Comment: @user15447158 Why are you logging the promise returned by `tech.findOne`? And yeah, it fails since `fru` isn't defined. Can you try logging what I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: sorry i don't really understand what you mean by "inside tech.findOne callback" @ArunKumarMohan

Comment: @user15447158 Ah, that's just a string. I added it for you to clearly see that the log comes from the callback inside `tech.findOne`. You could use `console.log('***', error, fru)` if you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, i just understand sorry my mind was somewhere else, so i just replace the console.log(err, fru) by console.log('***', error, fru') it's return nothing.. @ArunKumarMohan

Comment: @user15447158 You mean you don't even see `***` in the console?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan It's exaclty that

Comment: @user15447158 If there's no error, it should log `'*** null...'`. If there's an error, it should log the error. I honestly don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan, can it be just a bug?  Because if i put a console.log(data.fdd, '***') on the top of the findOne() it's working

Comment: @user15447158 No. I'm afraid I need a way to reproduce the issue to be able to help. One issue I see with your code is that if there's an error, you're just `console.log`ging it. You should `return` to stop execution. You could optionally send a message to the channel that something went wrong. I would also suggest you use `async/await` to make the code more readable and easy to follow.

Comment: I will you the async and await option, thanks you for trying to help me

Comment: My friend just found the issu, there was a ) causing the problem sorry for the trouble